# How can my ISP block certain websites if I'm using a VPN?

Tags: vpn, isp

Even  when I'm using a VPN (ExpressVPN), I still can't access certain websites. But  when I'm using Tor browser it loads them without a problem. So this must mean that my ISP somehow knows I'm trying to access those sites, even if I'm  using a VPN. How is this possible?

I tried using ExpressVPN's DNS servers or the 1.1.1.1 Cloudflare DNS server, neither works.

I  can use Tor for those websites, so that's not the problem, but Tor is slow  so there are times when I would rather use a VPN or use internet outside  of a browser, and it seems in those cases my ISP still knows what I'm  doing, which is a problem.

Comment: It seems like a misconfiguration; either you are not using the VPN at all for the site, or your DNS requests are not going through the VPN. Or someone else is blocking, per mentallurg's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a tool like `tracert` and you will see where your traffic is lost.

If your connection to the website is routed via VPN, your ISP provider cannot block it.

1) Check the routing when VPN is activated. It may happen, that traffic to some hosts or networks is routed not via VPN, but via your provider.

2) When traffic is really routed via VPN, then the VPN provider may block some hosts.

3) ExperssVPN is not an internet provider. It operates in the networks of different ISPs. Some of these ISPs may block your website. Try to select another ExpressVPN server, e.g. from different country. You say, via Tor it works. Check via what IP you are reaching the website, and in ExpressVPN select a server from the same country as Tor exit node.

Comment: Sir can you answer this question please. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/265889/can-service-providers-put-limits-eventhough-we-are-using-an-vpn